# Interpreting an illustration (fig. 311) in Robert Wearing's The Essential Woodworker

Tags: construction, carcass

Robert Wearing in *The Essential Woodworker* says (p. 153):

> Fig 311 shows a fairly typical bookcase with the shelves removed. The back consists of a frame with a centre muntin and four horizontal rails. Six panels are grooved into the frame. Such a framed back is a most effective way to stiffen up a carcase.

[image]

In the illustration, are we looking at the front or the back of the bookcase? If the back, then why does Wearing bother saying "with the shelves removed"? Do the "four horizontal rails" span the entire width of the carcase? Is the muntin that vertical piece in the center? Does the muntin divide the interior space of the bookcase in two or does it only run along the back of the carcase? Is the muntin anterior or posterior to the four horizontal rails? Is it attached to the rails or does it merely abut them? If attached, then in what fashion is it attached, or is that left open to personal taste? What parts in the illustration make up the frame, exactly? And since the six panels (I take it that these panels are the three big areas on the left and the three big areas on the right) are "grooved into the frame", does that mean that they have tongues that are fitted into the rails, and that all the rails are grooved?

Comment: Yeah in isolation this isn't that clear! But it's not in isolation in the book, in context some of this is clarified by the text above & below the excerpt, along with the associated pics. Are there nine question marks here or is it ten?? I know some of these are directly interdependent but as much as possible it's one question per Question on SE. And please remember we're not a substitute for your own research, we're not a "let me Google that for you" service. So for example you don't need to ask what a muntin is, see fig. 475 for starters! That alone should provide a core piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I want to add, I hope it's obvious that this is a wayyy overcomplicated back. Honestly I'm not sure why Wearing featured it, other than it's possible with hand tools only. But so are *all* of the alternatives, which are not just more common these days but are ubiquitous. The Victorian book he quotes goes on to say "in inferior work a tongue-and-groove back may be fitted" which is highly judgemental, but worse it's probably technically inaccurate given the high-dollar stuff *from before that era* that had T&G backs. So it's not just since those days that they became respectable.

Comment: @Graphus I did not ask what a muntin is; I asked which part of the illustration Wearing was referring to with the word 'muntin'. Fig 475 does not answer my question, I don't think. And there is no index that would have pointed me to that part of the book, which is dozens of pages after page 153. And my question is one question, namely, What is going on in figure 311? Thank you for your helpful historical note on tongue and groove backs.

Comment: I think it's fair to interpret which part is the muntin as not knowing what a muntin *is*, since it should be plainly evident based on what muntins are which part it is. Or something, I haven't had any coffee yet so Words Are Hard.

Comment: *"And my question is one question"* In order for someone to provide a proper Answer to the Question as asked, which is what we're instructed to do, they'd have to address every one of questions in the Question. And that is covered by [**you're asking too much**](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @Graphus "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." I don't think it would take a page, let alone a book, to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when a bookcase is discussed "with the shelves removed," it's referring to the back of the bookcase. The reason for mentioning the removal of the shelves is likely to provide a clear view of the structure and construction of the case itself without the shelves obstructing the view.

The horizontal rails would span the entire width of the carcase to provide stability and support. As for muntin it would indeed be the central vertical piece. Whether it divides the interior space or runs along the back would depend on the specific design of the bookcase.

Also in many designs, the muntin is posterior to the horizontal rails, meaning it's closer to the back of the bookcase. It could either be attached to the rails using joinery methods or merely abut them, again, depending on the specific design.

Now the frame.. It usually refers to the outer structure that holds everything together. It would typically include the sides of the bookcase and the horizontal rails. And yes, when panels are "grooved into the frame", it typically means that the panels have tongues that fit into grooves in the rails. The rails, muntin, and potentially the sides of the bookcase would generally all be grooved to accept the tongues of the panels.

Comment: If you're interested in the context for the above quote, [here's the book on Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/essentialwoodwor0000wear/mode/2up) and you want page 97. If you're not a member already you'd need to join (free) and borrow the book for an hour to be able to view the inside pages.